# Vertically align dropdown and input buttons

Tags: html

I have two buttons a dropdown and a text input that I want to vertically align. They are barely off by 1 px, but they are off and it is driving me nuts.

See the code below:

```html
<div style="text-align:center;padding-top:85px">

            <form role="form" class="form-inline ">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control selectWidth" style="width:auto">
                        <option> Primary Care Physician </option>
                        <option> Dermatologist </option>
                        <option> Orthodontist </option>
                    </select>       
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Zip Code"> 
            </form>

</div>
```

Comment: Could it be that you have spaces before and after your option text? Try removing the spaces, like so: ` <option>Primary Care Physician</option>`

Comment: Screenshot? Css?  Otherwise the snippet appears to renders centered, aligned along vertical axis.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="param" class="test row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <select class="form-control">
          <option> Primary Care Physician </option>
          <option> Dermatologist </option>
          <option> Orthodontist </option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
    <input type="url" class="form-control col-sm-8 invalidInput" placeholder="Enter Zip Code">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.test{
  width:50%;
}
```

[See JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zdms5jyj/)